# CSS animation effects the entire page paint real badly

Tags: html, css

**The Story**

I'm trying to achieve a continuous scroll animation on a `<ul>` tag that contains a list of images aligned horizontally, with a simple CSS keyframes animation, something like the old HTML `<marquee>` tag. I am okay with a continuous infinite repeated scroll or a back and forth style like the `animation-direction: alternate`(this is what I have done).

HTML

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="img1.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img2.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img3.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    transform: translateX(0);
    animation: animation1 20s linear infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

li {
    height: 6rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px .5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    width: 15rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 7rem;
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
    from {
        left: 0;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to {
        left: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

The above keyframes animation makes the entire page crappy. Every time I scroll up and down some portion of the page do a repaint. It also makes my laptop hotter. Please suggest a better way to achieve the animation or help me to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Use `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to force your browser to use gpu rendering, resulting in a smoother animation and lowering cpu usage. Replace the zeros with the values you need.

Comment: @Sirence How can I use that in this situation! Can you give a little more insight based on my implementation?

Comment: @Sirence Tried that one, I think the heating is minimized. But the rendering is not smooth yet. Is it due to the use of `left` property in the animation?

Comment: Is this smoother for you? https://jsfiddle.net/2mj98zwn/

Comment: yes, using `left` is slower than just using `transform: translate`. You can try adding `translateZ(0)` to your animaton

Comment: @Sirence It is perfect. But in my case the number of items is not fixed, it is dynamic. So a hardcoded value will not work. Do you have any suggestion on that?

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: @Sirence Yes, if it is difficult to achieve without using javascript.

Comment: I honestly have no quick idea how to do it in css. But this is how I would do it in js: https://jsfiddle.net/as1ftn4w/ Replace the number in `var id = setInterval(frame, 1)` for a different speed.

Comment: With offset: https://jsfiddle.net/us7p9qjw/2/